# CMake Error at IlmImf/cmake_install.cmake:84 (file): file INSTALL cannot find IlmImf.dll"

Tags: c, visual-studio, path, cmake, cmake-gui

I get the error here

```
1>------ Build started: Project: IlmImf, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Building Custom Rule D:/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/openexr/OpenEXR/IlmImf/CMakeLists.txt
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because D:\playing-for-data\renderdoc\renderdoc\3rdparty\openexr\OpenEXR\build\IlmImf\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  Generating b44ExpLogTable.h
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
2>------ Build started: Project: IlmImfUtil, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: IlmImfExamples, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: IlmImfFuzzTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: IlmImfTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: exrenvmap, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: exrheader, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: exrmakepreview, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
9>------ Build started: Project: exrmaketiled, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
7>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
3>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
10>------ Build started: Project: exrmultipart, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
11>------ Build started: Project: exrmultiview, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
12>------ Build started: Project: exrstdattr, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
9>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
5>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
13>------ Build started: Project: IlmImfUtilTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
11>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
10>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
12>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImf\Debug\IlmImf.lib'
13>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\IlmImfUtil\Debug\IlmImfUtil.lib'
14>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
14>  -- Install configuration: "Debug"
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/include/OpenEXR/OpenEXRConfig.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/TechnicalIntroduction.pdf
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/ReadingAndWritingImageFiles.pdf
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/OpenEXRFileLayout.pdf
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/MultiViewOpenEXR.pdf
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/InterpretingDeepPixels.pdf
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/TheoryDeepPixels.pdf
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/main.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/drawImage.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/rgbaInterfaceExamples.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/rgbaInterfaceTiledExamples.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/generalInterfaceExamples.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/lowLevelIoExamples.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/previewImageExamples.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/generalInterfaceTiledExamples.cpp
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/generalInterfaceTiledExamples.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/drawImage.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/rgbaInterfaceExamples.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/generalInterfaceExamples.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/rgbaInterfaceTiledExamples.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/lowLevelIoExamples.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/previewImageExamples.h
14>  -- Up-to-date: D:/openexr/share/doc/OpenEXR-2.2.0/examples/namespaceAlias.h
14>  CMake Error at IlmImf/cmake_install.cmake:84 (file):
14>    file INSTALL cannot find
14>    "D:/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/openexr/OpenEXR/build/IlmImf/Debug/IlmImf.dll".
14>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
14>    cmake_install.cmake:92 (include)
14>
14>
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
14>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 14 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have followed all the steps 1-4 of https://bitbucket.org/visinf/projects-2016-playing-for-data

I am not sure goes wrong. Please advise solutions.
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stephan, author of the paper, I got it fixed. Make sure you have something like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]